# Python. Why the length of the list changes after turning it from int to string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a bunch of users in a list called `UserList`.
And I do not want the output to have the square brackets, so I run this line:

```
UserList = [1,2,3,4...]
UserListNoBrackets = str(UserList).strip('[]')
```

But if I run:

```
len(UserList) #prints22 (which is correct).
```

However:

```
len(UserListNoBrackets) #prints 170 (whaaat?!)
```

Anyway, the output is actually correct (I'm pretty sure). Just wondering why that happens.

Comment: Becaue `len(str)` counts the number of characters. Also note that `strip('[]')` doesn't do anything because the substring is not present.

Comment: I thought about this and checked, but the number of characters is actually 131 maximum. Unless it also counts the commas and spaces?

Comment: @prp of course it counts the commas and spaces - those are characters too. Every single item in a string is a character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
UserListNoBrackets = str(UserList).strip('[]')
```

`UserListNoBrackets` is a string. A string is a sequence of characters, and `len(str)` returns the numbers of characters in the string. A comma is a character, a white space is a character, and the string represention of an integer has has many characters as there are digits in the integer. So obviously, the length of your `UserListNoBrackets` string is much greater than the length of you `UserList` list.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need `str.join`

**Ex:**

```
user_list = [1,2,3,4...]
print(",".join(map(str, user_list)))
```

**Note:**
Using `map` method to convert all int elements in list to string.

Comment: if I run ```len(",".join(map(str, user_list)))``` it returns 148

Comment: `len` returns the total count of your string.... try `print(len(",".join(map(str, [1,2,3,4]))))` and `print(len([1,2,3,4]))` to see the difference